# iOS broswer data -> Cache & Cookie for Phonegap App / Session?

Tags: ios, session, cordova, browser-cache, phonegap-build

I am producing a phonegap app which is half native and half web based.

When a user is required to upload data to the server, the webView (or atleast i belive this is what its called) loads an external webpage...

Now here is the catch. When I load the app (from soft reset and cooking and storage data cleard on the iPad) I get this screen

[small thin login bars - functions are not as in a normal web browser http://carbonyzed.co.uk/3.png](http://carbonyzed.co.uk/3.png)

however if I go into the web browser before opening the app which looks like this
[wide login bars - functions are normal in the web browser http://carbonyzed.co.uk/1.png](http://carbonyzed.co.uk/1.png) and then I go to re-launch/open the app, I get this

[wide login bars - functions are as normal web browser http://carbonyzed.co.uk/2.png](http://carbonyzed.co.uk/2.png)

then the functions are as normal in the app also, like mimicking the web browser. This seems to persist for a "Session" or as long as the app remains open/minimised but not exited as such.

It seems strange and I can't get my head round a solution to this?

Any ideas would be great.

OOH btw, it occurs in both 2.1 and 2.2 phonegap builds using build.phonegap.com

Henry

Comment: love it when people get stumped as well haha !!

Comment: still no thoughts people?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up actually going down a different route. This particular issue was actually the way the server handled access from different device types rather than the app design/development. However, I did find along my travels that using child browsers in later versions were far more stable.