# How to create a HTML link to a build.phonegap app?

Tags: ios, cordova, url-scheme, phonegap-build

I have run into several problems with iOS development through phonegap recently, and unusually people around here have been unable to discuss these issues and even together we have (for the first time I have ever seen) not had a single comment or answer for these topics...

See **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707936/make-a-page-that-redirects-back-to-ios-phonegap-app** and **[iOS broswer data -> Cache & Cookie for Phonegap App / Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705707/ios-broswer-data-cache-cookie-for-phonegap-app-session)**...

However, I have found "solutions" to get around these, but its by no means answers to the issues in question which are still outstanding... just simply doing it a completely different way.

However, despite loosing web-view in phonegap, in an attempt to get around **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707936/make-a-page-that-redirects-back-to-ios-phonegap-app** I now have some issue that are outstanding...

**I need to be able to navigate back to my App from the web-system !!!**

However, I have no idea how. I have read info on creating URL Schema, but I am not sure if this is even possible through build.phonegap at all... and it seems faily complicated. Does anybody know of a way for **iOS safari** to do one of two things

**Either**

> Open the app that is running in the background

or

> close the current browser tab and navigate back to the app in the background.

***The closing tab idea would be good, but not essential***

Look forward to everyone thoughts and opinions on this one...

Henry

Comment: Your phonegap build process is not that much different from any other app's, so you can add the necessary properties to the .plist files of your application, and build it without problems.

Comment: however, we don't have the .plist file with a build.phonegap app. it creates all these for you, you essentially upload a glorified mobile optimised HTML site...

Comment: So you're building with some other cloud service rather than on a machine of your own?
I suppose you aren't using any cordova plugins either then?

Comment: It might be worth to ask the boys over at build.phonegap.com if there is any way to do this, i checked http://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml for you, but it does not state support for url schemas.
If you want to do this, building the app yourself *might* be the only way.

Comment: noooooooo...... haha Thanks for your time Timothy, much appreciated :D

Comment: You're welcome, i hope you can work something out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible using PhoneGap Build in 2.2 and previous. Potentially a feature top be released in newer versions of Cordova/Phonegap

Answer (score 1):

You can create an url scheme for any application you make yourself.

[See tutorial here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

It's not as terribly complicated as one would think, and the required objective-c code is minimal.

Once you have done this, you can use your own url scheme to launch your phonegap application from safari with a hyperlink.
This would not close the tab (you could do this with javascript if you wanted to)
but does put safari in the background, and opens your phonegap app.
(whether it is already running in the background or not)

It is even possible to pass data to the app using your url scheme.

Comment: however, we don't have the .plist file with a build.phonegap app. it creates all these for you, you essentially upload a glorified mobile optimised HTML site...